# Why does PROC UNIVARIATE NOPRINT PLOTS display no output?

Tags: sas

I have a simple data set that I would like to analyze using stem-and-leaf/boxplots, but I only want the textual graphs, not the output tables. This is the data step:

```
DATA CLINIC;
   INPUT ID     $ 1-3
         GENDER $   4
         RACE   $   5
         HR       6-8
         SBP      9-11
         DBP     12-14
         N_PROC  15-16;
   AVE_BP = DBP + (SBP - DBP)/3;
DATALINES;
001MW08013008010
002FW08811007205
003MB05018810002
004FB   10806801
005MW06812208204
006FB101   07404
007FW07810406603
008MW04811207006
009FB07719011009
010FB06616410610
;
```

I'm using `proc univariate`, but I'd like to suppress the output of only the tables, not the plots themselves. Using the `noprint` statement, all output is suppressed:

```
proc univariate noprint;
var SBP DBP;
```

Using only the `plots` option, no output is suppressed, so both the plots and the tables are shown.

```
proc univariate plots;
    var SBP DBP;
```

Obviously, specifying both doesn't work either.

```
proc univariate plots noprint;
    var SBP DBP;
```

Is there any way to suppress only the tables, not the plots themselves?

UPDATE: I worked the suggested code into my full code sample, and both the tables and the plots are still displayed. Here is the full code sample, run in a fresh SAS session on a different machine than the previous code (both machines use SAS 9.3).

```
PROC DATASETS LIBRARY=WORK;
DELETE clinic;

DATA clinic;
INPUT @1 ID $ 3. @4 GENDER $ 1. @5 RACE $ 1.
      @6 HR 3. @9 SBP 3. @12 DBP 3. @15 N_PROC 2.;

AVE_BP = DBP + (SBP - DBP) / 3;

DATALINES;
001MW08013008010
002FW08811007205
003MB05018810002
004FB   10806801
005MW06812208204
006FB101   07404
007FW07810406603
008MW04811207006
009FB07719011009
010FB06616410610
;

PROC MEANS DATA=clinic N MEAN STD CLM MEDIAN;
TITLE "Means";
VAR SBP DBP AVE_BP;

ODS TRACE ON;
ODS SELECT Plots;
PROC UNIVARIATE DATA=clinic PLOTS;
TITLE "Plots";
VAR SBP DBP;
RUN;
ODS TRACE OFF;
ODS SELECT ALL;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since version 8, when Output Delivery System (ODS) was added to SAS, I'm a big fan of it.

1. Use `ods trace on;` + original code (proc univariate... here) to determine (from LOG) what outputs is it producing (also visible in Results Tree).
2. Then use `ods select ...;` to make you selection.
3. Use `ods select all;` to reset back.

> ```
> ods trace on;
> ods select Plots;
> proc univariate plots;
> var SBP DBP;
> run;
> ods trace off;
> ```

ODS is much more then this, certainly worth studying - make a search for ODS user guide.

Comment: Are you sure, you're not looking at previous results?

Comment: Yeah, this definitely should work.  Try running a simple version in a new SAS session: `ods trace on;
ods select Plots;
proc univariate plots data=sashelp.class;
var age height;
run;
ods trace off;
ods select all;` - this works cleanly, and commenting out the ODS select plots; line adds back in the tables.

Comment: @Joe See my update in the question. This isn't working for me in a fresh SAS session.

Comment: @vasja Yes, I'm sure. I'm using a new SAS session on a different machine.

Comment: You need to add the RUN statement for the earlier PROC MEANS in order for this to behave as expected.  Good practice is to always terminate procedures (and data steps) via run or quit, not just to wait for the next boundary to happen naturally - or you get things like this.

Comment: @Joe Thanks for the tip; adding run after the PROC DATASETS and PROC MEANS solved the problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand why do people omit RUN; statements, worse the QUIT; in PROC DATASETS. This should be, and as you can see, is punished.